# Isometries in metric $L_n$

Tags: normed-spaces

Let's define distance between the points in 2-d space: $$d = \sqrt[n]{(x_1 - x_2) ^ n + (y_1 - y_2) ^ n},\quad n > 2$$
The isometries (linear transformations that preserves the length of vectors) in this space seem confusing to me. How to define the angle between vectors?

Comment: What is a 'rotate'?

Comment: Transformation that preserves the length of the vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The isometries of this space are the [symmetries of the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_groups#The_symmetry_group_of_a_square_-_dihedral_group_of_order_8), dihedral group with 8 elements. This is because the unit ball for the metric has those symmetries and no others; an isometry must map it onto itself.

Generally, one doesn't define an angle between vectors in a normed space. If you really want to, take a look at the *semi-inner product* 
$$ [u,v] = \frac{\sum {u_iv_i|v_i|^{n-2}}}{\left(\sum |v_i|^{n}\right)^{(n-2)/n}}$$
which has a bit of useful properties such as $[u,u]=\|u\|^2$, $|[u,v]|\le \|u\|\|v\|$ and linearity in $u$.

But it's non-symmetric, so $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{[u,v]}{\|u\|\|v\|}\right)$ and $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{[v,u]}{\|v\|\|u\|}\right)$ give you two different angle values.